# "Loader Constraint Violation" when converting Eclipse dynamic web project to Maven

Tags: eclipse, maven, jakarta-ee

I have created a simple dynamic web application in eclipse , Java web. And I have used Spring mvc architecture . The program is working fine it has a simple form handling function. Now i want to convert my project in to a Maven project but when I go Configuration->convert to maven, It gives me a "Loader Constraint Violation" error. I'm using Eclipse Luna.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe there is a problem with the maven plug-in you installed. try re install the plug-in and see

Comment: yes there was a problem with configuration. Solved. Thanks @Sandun